# why is my ASP.NET button control not firing JQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

First of all the button does not fire up the jquery dialog and
When the page loads, i check the console for errors and I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" which is pointing to     $("#dialog").dialog({

Here are my codes below.

Default.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cv1" ControlToValidate="fupCV"     ClientValidationFunction="validate"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fupCV"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUpload_OnClick" Text="Upload"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDialog" OnClientClick="return false;" Text="Open Dialog"/>
</div>
</form>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    This is a popup
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript1.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnUpload').attr('disable', 'disable');

$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        Accept: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});

$("#btnDialog").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.dialog()` is part of jQuery UI, not jQuery

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

I don't see jQuery UI included anywhere in your source.

Comment: Thanks Eric, straight forward and concise!. I did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also for id ending something like:

```
$('input:submit[id$=btnDialog]')).click(function () {});
```